# How to get tags for amazon dynamo db in java sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to get tags associated with dynamodb table. I could not find anything in api. any one guide me

Comment: What do you mean by tags associated with DynamoDB table? Please provide more details.

Comment: To list all of the tags associated with the Movies table, we can fire below command, like i want get list of tags for table with java api :


$ aws dynamodb list-tags-of-resource \ --resource-arn arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789012:table/Movies

Comment: So you are looking for the similar thing on Java code?

Comment: Exactly , it is for dynamo Db. Thanks

Comment: I think you can use the [listTagsOfResource](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/api-permissions-reference.html) method from the Java API :)

Comment: @TachúSalamanca ,Could you please provide any sample java code for listTagsOfResource method to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the class and method.

> Class: AmazonDynamoDBClient
>
> Method:
> ListTagsOfResourceResult  listTagsOfResource(ListTagsOfResourceRequest
> listTagsOfResourceRequest) List all tags on an Amazon DynamoDB
> resource.

**Sample code:**

```
ListTagsOfResourceRequest listTagsOfResourceRequest = new ListTagsOfResourceRequest()
                .withResourceArn("arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789012:table/Movies");
        return dynamoDBClient.listTagsOfResource(listTagsOfResourceRequest);
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html